# JavaFX TableView scrolling colors different row that aren't ment to be colored

Tags: javafx, scroll, tableview, background-color, tablerow

Forum,

I have created a Tableview. Every row is filled with the information given by each "Steckerpin"-object. Using RowFactory I color the backround of each row depending on the value of the attribute "Zustand" of every object ("Steckerpin").

The problem is, when the table becomes scrollable, the new appearing row are coloured in a similar order as the colored rows in the beginning. But those rows shouldn't be colored, because their attribute "Zustand" hasn't changed.

[Colored rows before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWgp7.png)

[New appearing rows after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjcz5.png)

If I scroll to the end of the table, the wrong colored rows become white again.

I have read that it is a common problem using tableviews in combination with RowFactory, because the rows are reused once you start scrolling.

Here is my code using the RowFactory:

```java
durchgangsTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Steckerpin>() {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Steckerpin item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(okZustString)) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ok"), true);
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(fehlerZustString)) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), true);
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(prüfZustString)) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pending"), true);
        }
    }
});
```

I have read a couple of similar questions, but I can't find a solution for my problem. So I would be very grateful for some help.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll, existing rows are reused to display new items. So, for example, if you had a row which displayed an item which was in an "error" state, and it is reused for an item which is in an "ok" state, then both pseudoclasses will be set to `true`.

Consequently, you need to set all pseudoclasses to the correct state under all conditions:

```
durchgangsTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Steckerpin>() {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Steckerpin item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setStyle("");
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ok"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pending"), false);
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(okZustString)) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ok"), true);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pending"), false);
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(fehlerZustString)) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ok"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), true);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pending"), false);
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(prüfZustString)) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ok"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pending"), true);
        } else {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ok"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error"), false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pending"), false);
        }
    }
});
```

Equivalently, with less code:

```
durchgangsTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Steckerpin>() {

    private final List<String> states = List.of("ok", "error", "pending");

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Steckerpin item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setStyle("");
            updateState(null);
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(okZustString)) {
            updateState("ok");
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(fehlerZustString)) {
            updateState("error");
        } else if (item.getZustand().equals(prüfZustString)) {
            updateState("pending");
        } else {
            updateState(null);
        }
    }

    private void updateState(String newState) {
        states.forEach(state ->
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass(state), state.equals(newState)));
    }

});
```

Comment: Hey first of all thank you for fast answer. Unfortunatelly that didn't solve the issue, but this way of coding the pseudoClasses is very nice.

Comment: @KSchenk Check again: I noticed a bug in the solution and just updated it.

Comment: @KSchenk Which Java version are you using? That was introduced in Java 9. (And I assume you imported `java.util.List`.) You can use `Arrays.asList(...)` instead if you're still using an earlier version.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 at the moment

Comment: So `Arrays.asList(...)` should work in place of `List.of(...)`. (Or the first version, with the repeated statements, should work too.)

Comment: please read the api doc of List .. no rocket science, just plain java ..

Comment: The solution using the updateState method worked. Thank you very much. I found another solution by refreshing the table at the end of the updateItem method, but it made the scrolling stutter a bit. With your solution it scrolls smothly thank you very much @James_D